# Python get content from the loaded webpage

Tags: python, testing, automation

In my Python Script, I would like to get content from the page that I launched using this script:

```
import webbrowser

url = 'https://yahoo.com'

webbrowser.get('Chrome').open_new(url)
```

I know how to get using Selenium Webdriver, and have never get it through script itself.

any ideas would helpful,
Thanks

Comment: So if you're not using a webdriver, is your goal just to scrape a specified web page? The python Requests library works very well for this.

Comment: my goal is to launch google chrome browser, then open url yahoo.com, after that I would like get some content to make sure nothing was blocking these events, and webpage loaded as expected.

Comment: The `webbrowser` library is just a trivial wrapper that knows how to find the popular browsers on the popular platforms and tell them to open a page. There's no way to interact with the browser beyond that.

Comment: Well, there's not _no_ way. You could automate Chrome via the windowing system—do a screen grab, move the mouse over to the scrollbar, etc. Or you could install a Chrome extension that ends messages to your Python script on various browser events. But nothing you'd actually _want_ to do.

Comment: thanks, @abarnert so the only one way to use webdriver?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you're trying to do what selenium does, then yes, you need selenium (or some other webdriver), you can't do it with webbrowser.

Comment: If you're trying to look for a way to improve speed, it's really hard to make anything "fast" when it comes to front-end web scraping. Generally, the best method is to find a way to get rid of the front-end web scraping component all together so that you don't need a web driver. Why exactly do you need Chrome to open? Also a side note, but if you're open to switching languages, Geb and Groovy are very commonly used for this type of scraping, but they too require a web driver.